How to add overrides in "MODULE.tools" file in Bazel?
I want to use a local buildozer Bazel Module while building Bazel from source.
In MODULES.bazel file, I could override the bazel_dep by using local_path_override similar to remoteapis here.
However same approach doesn't work in src/MODULE.tools , it still pulls buildozer from BCR. How to use a local repo in src/MODULE.tools file?

MODULE.tools is not a Bazel-specific file. The file get read here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/34b926bceba798820b369a47d1a7b7ff1634d277/src/create_embedded_tools.py#L31
It is used via Bazel's extension mechanism. Since MODULE.tools is not an "official" Bazel file you can not override it. You also have the supporting code.

Thanks @Vertexwahn. Is this a limitation then? Is there any way to force a dep listed under MODULES.tools to use local path?
